# How to do number formatting in android. I applied lot of code but its not working any more

Tags: android, number-formatting

I want to do number formatting of dealer balance value.

```
holder.name.setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("name").toString());
holder.email.setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("email").toString());
holder.phone.setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("mobile").toString());     holder.address.setText(Address);
holder.tin.setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("tinnumber").toString());

holder.dealer_balance.setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("remain_amount").toString());
DecimalFormat amount_formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##,###"); //not statndard format
String finalamt = amount_formatter.format(jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("remain_amount").toString());
holder.dealer_balance.setText(finalamt);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
txtv.setText(formatter.format(yourAmount));
```

Comment: i want to convert holder value first then set to the holder

Comment: I did not get your approach. As per my understanding of code you posted, you are retrieving value from JSON array and setting it to dealer balance.
Try to copy the value to double variable before setting it to TextView. It can work.

Comment: sir i just want to convert JSON value and set to the text view.

Comment: I want to show json value like this--------10,000, which means seprated by commas.

Comment: Yes. Get your json values, cast it to double and pass it to formatter. It will work.

Comment: Accept it as answer